# Pushing Objects in Postgress jsonb

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Im pushing an array of obects via axios to postgress that looks like:

```
warehouses = 
  [
    {Name : "Patrick", Table : "patrick"},
    {Name : "Cape", Table : "cape"},
  ]
```

However, postgress requires the syntax to look like this:

```
  [
    {"Name" : "Patrick", "Table" : "patrick"},
    {"Name" : "Cape", "Table" : "cape"},
  ]
```

** Name and Table need to be passed as strings

Here is the Postgress Call:

```
`UPDATE users SET warehouse_access = '${req.body.warehouses}' ::jsonb
  WHERE dod_id = '${req.body.DoD}'`,
```

Any suggestions?

Push objects to a jsonb column in postgress

Comment: Convert it to JSON?

Comment: Idk why I didn’t think about that. 

Hit it with a JSON.stringify and we are now rolling!